# Chrome Sockets in a Web Worker?

Tags: javascript, sockets, google-chrome, web-worker

I have a Chrome packaged application that receives UDP packets containing audio data using [Chrome.sockets.udp](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/sockets_udp) and plays them using the Web Audio API. As you can imagine, this ends up being a pretty heavy load on the CPU, and I start dropping packets if I try to open up another Chrome window, which leads me to believe that once I start adding interactive UI elements I'll start running into problems. I wanted to pack up all this stuff nicely in a Web Worker to avoid that, but when I try to do so and declare `var socket = chrome.sockets.udp;` in my Web Worker, I end up getting an `Uncaught ReferenceError: chrome is not defined` when I try to use it. Is it not possible to use the Chrome sockets API in a Web Worker? It seems like a Web Worker would be a perfect use case for such a thing.

Comment: You can't use the chrome API in webworkers. I am using the udp and tcp, and i just hooked it up to post packets straight to the web worker for processing. It helped a lot, but it does suck you can use the chrome API in them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use transferable objects to pass Blob/Buffer to the web worker process from the main application.

Comment: Thanks for the help. This was the correct way of going about it- unfortunately, Web Audio contexts currently are unsupported in Web Workers, so for my purposes this is moot. Thanks anyway.